# Better Way to Check for Null Value in Linq Path

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Here is an example of an assignment to a linq path pulled from code first...

```
applicants = appRegistrations
             .ToList()
             .Select(c => new ApplicantList() { 
             PartnerType = c.Participant != null ? c.Participant.PartnerType != null ? c.Participant.PartnerType.PartnerTypeName : "" : ""
});
```

Notice the null checks - is there a more elegant way I can write this code considering Participant AND PartnerType could be null?

I just hate checking for nulls on each property.

Comment: How is it related to LINQ at all? Why not a simple `if`? `string PartnerType = "";
            if(c.Participant != null c.Participant.PartnerType != null) 
                partnerType = c.Participant.PartnerType.PartnerTypeName;` That's the most readable way and it's concise as well.

Comment: Sorry - i updated my question to be more specific to how its related to linq.

Comment: BTW - I believe your example of `if(c.Participant != null c.Participant.PartnerType != null)` will raise an exception if c.Participant is null

Comment: no, `c.Participant` cannot be null since that was checked in the if. However, i'm missing the `&&` operator(typo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if one of both are `null`:

```
List<ApplicantList> applicants = appRegistrations
    .Select(ar => c.Participant == null || c.Participant.PartnerType == null 
                  ? "" : c.Participant.PartnerType.PartnerTypeName)
    .Select(str => new ApplicantList { PartnerType = str })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it a little bit:

```
PartnerType = c.Participant != null && c.Participant.PartnerType != null 
            ? c.Participant.PartnerType.PartnerTypeName 
            : ""
```

Comment: What happens if c.Participant is null - won't that raise an exception when it hits c.Participant.PartnerType?

Comment: No, && is a short-circuit conditional boolean operator, so if `c.Participat == null` it won't test `c.Participant.PartnerType != null`. Ref. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you construct the objects such as `Participant`, **make sure that the properties are never null**. Think if `null` is a valid value for a `Participant`? If not then you should never allow it to be null. Take a constructor parameter and add a guard clause to check for nulls. Otherwise initialize them to a `default` value.

Also, see [NULL Reference Pattern](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/NullObject.aspx).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if I make sure the properties are never null it messed with code first/entity framework. If those property create an empty object - then whenever a class that contains that property is added to the database it will create a bunch of empty records. Trying to explain this the best i can - apologize if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Then you can add a method on the 'c' object to get a PartnerTypeName and hide your checks in that method. Simply call c.GetPartnerTypeName();